# How to get number of the system calls after the kernel boot in xv6?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, posix, fork

I want to write a simple "C" program to find number of system calls after OS boot. I am following other system calls like fork() or getpid() and basically copying most of their stuff. I am unsure where/when I should increase my counter? Any example?

Is it a good idea to define the counter in kernel/syscall.c and increment it accordingly?

```
void
syscall(void)
{
  int num;
  counter++; //mona
  num = proc->tf->eax;
  if(num > 0 && num < NELEM(syscalls) && syscalls[num] != NULL) {
    proc->tf->eax = syscalls[num]();
  } else {
    cprintf("%d %s: unknown sys call %d\n",
            proc->pid, proc->name, num);
    proc->tf->eax = -1;
  }
}
```

Also here's the code I've got so far in kernel/sysproc.c for my trivial system call:

```
sys_getsyscallinfo(void)
{

 return counter;  //mona
}
```

However I receive this error:

```
kernel/sysproc.c: In function ‘sys_getsyscallinfo’:
kernel/sysproc.c:48: error: ‘counter’ undeclared (first use in this function)
kernel/sysproc.c:48: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
kernel/sysproc.c:48: error: for each function it appears in.)
make: *** [kernel/sysproc.o] Error 1
```

Comment: What do you mean by - "I am following other system calls like fork() or getpid() and basically copying most of their stuff" ? If you have some code, please post it.

Comment: @VivekS following xv6 code in http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2012/xv6.html you can write all the necessary (basic) code for a simple systemcall. I followed getpid for example using "grep -irn getid *" command and tried to follow where it has been defined/used and did the same for my own systemcall. But I am not sure if I should simply call a counter whenever we call the system trap or not. or how should we approach achieving number of system calls after boot.

Comment: Where do you plan to increment the counter ? Inside you code ? Trap is a software interrupt to the OS to change contexts and execute a function present in the kernel to do some work. As such, every system call issues a trap and these functions are spread out across many files, in glibc as well other files. Correct me if I am not understanding your problem .

Comment: where is counter defined in sys_getsyscallinfo ? counter is a local variable defined inside syscall which calls sys_getsyscallinfo (assuming that is your system call) when you call your system call from userspace. Are you aware of how system calls are handled in an OS ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I defined a counter variable as extern int in `kernel/defs.h` and made use of it in syscall definition as the return value in `kernel/sysproc.c` and increased it where all trap handlings is done in `kernel/syscall.c`. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This would need editing entry.S file. Last time I was with the kernel, it was in `.../arch/kernel/` directory. In that file, it first validates the system call, the call it using `call` instruction. You would have to do things after this validation and before system call in actually put.

You need not worry about how do I access variables in User Land, there is base pointer in that entry.S.

By the way this is 'new' way of calling system call(thanks to P II+ processors).. initially there used to be software interrupt `int 0x80`. So also check with which version of kernel you are working on.

I may be wrong here.. I am just explaining one way(which is probably worst and/or wrong) based on some knowledge. if You/someone_else implement this, please post success/failure with minimal code.

Once I get time out of Windows(chances are less) I am going to write this code myself.

Comment: I added my system call to user/usys.S system calls like so : http://paste.ubuntu.com/6113766/ I am writing this for xv6 OS.

Comment: I have not worked on Xv6. So you would need to check yourself where exactly system calls are being called, and also if they make use of processor's SYSENTER and SYSEXIT facility. But I think basics would remain the same. This logic should work

Comment: What user2705939 is saying is that, when you call a system call from userland, there is an entrypoint in the kernel which gets called to interpret this system call (based on its number) and take action accordingly. You need to figure out this entry point, add a counter that increments everytime this function is entered and then find some way of returning this counter to userspace.

Comment: The problem is, there generally is never a single entry point, though I might be wrong. The userspace -> kernel interface keeps evolving to find better and efficient ways of communication and hence you might find multiple entry points for system calls. Read this file for some understanding on how this is done in Linux. https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/x86/entry_64.txt?id=refs/tags/v3.11

Comment: @VivekS your link by no means proving that there can be multiple entry points for system calls. You are basically missing the basics. From the very your link in the comments, it is talking about user mode to kernel mode. And one more thing.. did you even read your links in the answer completely? from your own link(2nd link) `One is entry.S, an entry point to all system calls which initializes the treatment of exceptions`. Please provide more claims stating there can be more than one entry point to system calls.

Comment: @user2705939 syscall, sysenter, int 0x80 ? All these methods have the same entry point inside the kernel ?

Comment: @Vivek, there is some confusion. The entry point I am talking about, and this question is related to, is NOT kernel's main function. We are talking about something--> whenever there is system call made, one function is called, which actually calls system call. There used to be software interrupts which were handled which is replaced by SYSENTER and SYSEXIT, so for every system call made(from userland), this mechanism is always followed. It is present in entry.S, where thread's context, sys call validation work is done. And I strongly believe that this is unique.

Comment: Does kernel have a main function ? If I implement two system calls, one using sysenter and the other using syscall, do both these methods end up in the same entry point function ? What if I use 0x80 and implement another system call ? Do you mean to say that an OS will support only one means of making a call to system to execute a privileged operation ?

Comment: Thanks for being specific  1--> That depends on Kernel you are talking about. Unix has a main function, others may name it differently, but they have some or the other entry point function, which is generally called by bootloader.

Comment: 2&3 --> No matter how you implement system call, it is NEVER going to invoke kernel's main/entry point function. You see, kernel provides services to User Space programs, but it is still a program, calling several routines, which is running all the time since system started, so there is no need to call kernel's entry point when handling a system call

Comment: 4 --> No. OS will provide several mechanisms, but they all have to follow set of rules, like saving context of currently running process, and then only going to kernel mode. Mechanisms can be categorized into interrupts, exceptions, system calls.